# Counting the number of raws with Join and GroupBy - mysql , knex

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I have this table:

table foo

```
id | bar_id | user_id
-----------------
1  |    3   |   1
2  |    5   |   1
3  |    6   |   2
4  |    5   |   1
5  |    3   |   2
```

table bar

```
id | title | description
------------------------
3  | hey   |  desc1
5  | ola   |  desc 2
6  | vassup | desc 3
```

Then I have this query

```
const basequery = knex
  .select('bar.*')
  .from('bar')
  .join('foo', 'foo.bar_id', 'bar.id')
  .groupBy('foo.bar_id')
  .whereIn('foo.user_id', 1);
```

This will return:

```
id | title | description
-----------------------
3  | hey   | desc 1
5  | ola   | desc 2
```

which is correct.

Basically I'm reusing that basequery multiple times on the file.

Then I want to count the number of rows returned by this.

```
basequery.clone().countDistinct(`bar.id as total`)
```

What I'm expecting is:

```
id | title | description | total
--------------------------------
3  | hey   | desc 1      |  2
```

because there are 2 columns on the foo table with id = 1 and grouped by bar_id. I want to count the number of column returned by the first query as "total".

However, it returns this:

```
id | title | description | total
--------------------------------
3  | hey   | desc 1      |  1
5  | ola   | desc 2      |  2
```

Any help would greatly appreciated

Comment: The output you are getting is totally expected if you look at the underlying SQL.  If you want that total column, you may need to bring it in using a native subquery.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But if I remove the ` .groupBy('foo.bar_id')` It works as my what I'm expecting it. hmmmm

Comment: That query with `GROUP BY` removed is not valid and wouldn't even run on certain versions of MySQL (or practically any other database).  I could give you a raw MySQL query for this, but I don't know Knex so it might not be what you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'll accept raw queries as answer. I could just transform them to knex then. :)

Comment: You appear to want something like the value of .select('t.*').from(value of the first expression, t).countDistinct('id as total'), but you appear to be asking for the value of the extension of the first expression by .countdistinct('bar.id as total'). But what is your criterion for dropping rows from the query that is "correct"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Knex, but if Knex is anything like Laravel, then you would almost certainly need to use some raw query functionality to get the output you want here.  The `total` you want in the output is just the total number of records in thr query itself.  Unfortunately, there is no trick we can use in MySQL to get that count without running the actual query.  In the raw query below, I use a non correlated subquery to bring in the total.

```
SELECT
    b.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT b.id FROM bar b INNER JOIN foo f ON f.bar_id = b.id
     WHERE f.user_id IN (1) GROUP BY f.bar_id) t) total
FROM bar b
INNER JOIN foo f
    ON f.bar_id = b.id
WHERE f.user_id IN (1)
GROUP BY f.bar_id
```

To be clear, the subquery in the above `SELECT` list is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT b.id
    FROM bar b
    INNER JOIN foo f
        ON f.bar_id = b.id
    WHERE f.user_id IN (1)
    GROUP BY f.bar_id
) t
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, btw it says `Subquery returns more than 1 row`. I think the subquery returns the same output I get on my current query, and it somehow causes an issue.

Comment: @IamL Sorry, I updated my answer.  We need to query the count from your current query, so just wrap what I originally had with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (...)`.

Comment: Awesome, this works... aside from one more thing , I think you forgot to add "Alias" to the other subquery, since it will return "Every derived table must have its own alias" error. I added "AS total" just after each closing parenthesis and it works. thanks!

Comment: isn't it `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT b.id FROM bar b INNER JOIN foo f ON f.tag_id = b.id
     WHERE f.user_id IN (1) GROUP BY f.bar_id) as total ) as total` ? since there are 2 subquery?

Comment: You're right again...I updated the answer.  I didn't test this, because I don't have your data, hence the chance for a typo is fairly high.